# Terminal initiation error

Tags: gnome-terminal, bashrc, anaconda, powerline-plugin

[Error while opening terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMy1y.png)

I was using powerline. I also used anaconda(python 2.7 version). For some reasons I uninstall anaconda and reinstall anacanda(python 3.6 version).

Now while I am opening terminal an error message shows,

```
-bash: /home/sbmaruf/.local/bin/powerline-daemon: /home/sbmaruf/anaconda2/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
-bash: /home/sbmaruf/.local/bin/powerline-config: /home/sbmaruf/anaconda2/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
-bash: /home/sbmaruf/.local/bin/powerline-config: /home/sbmaruf/anaconda2/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
-bash: /home/sbmaruf/.local/bin/powerline-config: /home/sbmaruf/anaconda2/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
-bash: /home/sbmaruf/.local/bin/powerline-config: /home/sbmaruf/anaconda2/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I am also adding my .bashrc file so that you can suggest me for necessary update,

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

# added by Anaconda2 4.0.0 installer

if command -v tmux>/dev/null; then
  [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]] && [ -z $TMUX ] && exec tmux
fi


export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
export POWERLINE_COMMAND=powerline
export POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND=powerline-config
powerline-daemon -q
POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1
POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1
. ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh

# added by Anaconda3 4.3.1 installer
export PATH="/home/sbmaruf/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"


if [ -f ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh ]; then
    source ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
fi
export TERM=xterm-256color

if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ]; then
    PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
fi
export POWERLINE_COMMAND=powerline



BASE16_SHELL=$HOME/.config/base16-shell/
[ -n "$PS1" ] && [ -s $BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh ] && eval "$($BASE16_SHELL/profile_helper.sh)"
```

I am also adding my powerline-config file From ( /home/sbmaruf/.local/bin/powerline-config),

```
#!/home/sbmaruf/anaconda2/bin/python
# vim:fileencoding=utf-8:noet
from __future__ import (unicode_literals, division, absolute_import, print_function)

try:
    from powerline.commands.config import get_argparser
except ImportError:
    import sys
    import os
    sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(os.path.realpath(__file__)))))
    from powerline.commands.config import get_argparser

import powerline.bindings.config as config


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = get_argparser()
    args = parser.parse_args()

    pl = config.create_powerline_logger(args)

    args.function(pl, args)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would remove this part:

```
# added by Anaconda2 4.0.0 installer

if command -v tmux>/dev/null; then
  [[ ! $TERM =~ screen ]] && [ -z $TMUX ] && exec tmux
fi

export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"
export POWERLINE_COMMAND=powerline
export POWERLINE_CONFIG_COMMAND=powerline-config
powerline-daemon -q
POWERLINE_BASH_CONTINUATION=1
POWERLINE_BASH_SELECT=1
. ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh

# added by Anaconda3 4.3.1 installer
export PATH="/home/sbmaruf/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"


if [ -f ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh ]; then
    source ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh
fi
```

You have lines sourcing `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/powerline/bindings/bash/powerline.sh`
This file probably tries to start `/home/sbmaruf/.local/bin/powerline-config` which has shebang pointing `#!/home/sbmaruf/anaconda2/bin/python` as your interpreter.

Comment: In that case my powerline will be removed from terminal.

Comment: YOu can try to reinstall this powerline package, but I don't know if it helps. You can also try to create a new user or manually edit all the files called by powerline.